# Generate specified increment steps but fill in the previous values in between each step?

Tags: r, dplyr

I supposed I want to generate a vector with incremental steps like so:

```
> seq(1, 20, by=5)
[1]  1  6 11 16
```

however what I really want is to return a vector that is filled with the previous value up to the next step?

```
1,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,6,11,11,11,11,11,16
```

can this be done with without some convoluted looping?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Request OP:

```
x <- seq(1, 20, by=5)
y <- c(rep(x[-length(x)], each=5), x[length(x)])

y[duplicated(y)] <- 0

 [1]  1  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0 16
```

Here is an alternative approach:
We use `length` to identify the last value in the vector. Subset first all values except the last and repeat each 5 times, as next step we put the last value again into the vector with `c()`:

```
x <- seq(1, 20, by=5)
c(rep(x[-length(x)], each=5), x[length(x)])

 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11 16
```

Comment: this is great; is there any way to fill it with blanks/zeros instead? for example, ```1 0 0 0  0 6 0 0 0 0 11 0  0 0 0 16```

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: holly molly that is a clever - learn something new everyday. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

We could use `length.out`

```
rep(seq(1, 20, by = 5), each = 5, length.out = 16)
[1]  1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11 16
```

Comment: this is neat; didn't realized there was a argument you can add. do you think is possible to fill it with 0 or blanks  " " instead? ```1 0 0 0  0 6 0 0 0 0 11 0  0 0 0 16```

Comment: @Ahdee you can do this in multiple ways `replace(integer(16), x, x)` where `x <- seq(1, 20, 5)` or from the `rep` step` `out <- rep(seq(1, 20, by = 5), each = 5, length.out = 16) ;out *!duplicated(out)`

Answer (score 1):

- We can use

```
x <- seq(1, 20, by=5)

rep(x , times = c(diff(x) , 1))

#> [1]  1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11 16
```